# Python regex 2 or statments in 1 string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get law article from string, but my regex is splitting at every law article.

```
def kanunMaddesi(madde):
    r1 = re.compile("[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{1,2}|[-|\/|.|_| ][a-zA-Z]{1}")
    return r1.findall(madde)

madde = (kanunMaddesi("5237SA 116/1 119/1 C 58/6 53/1 58 58/7."))
```

Python result in list: `['116/1', '119/1', ' C']`

I expected: `['116/1', '119/1 C']`

String = `5237SA 116/1 119/1 C 58/6 53/1 58 58/7.`

I've tried this regular expression

```
[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{1,2}|[-|\/|.|_| ][a-zA-Z]{1}
```

This regular expression result is:
`5237SA (116/1) (119/1) (C) 58/6 53/1 58 58/7.`

My expected result:
`5237SA (116/1) (119/1 C) 58/6 53/1 58 58/7.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ([Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3v1xE/3)):

```py
import re

def kanunMaddesi(madde):
    r1 = re.compile(r"\b\d{3}\/\d{1,2}(?:[\/._ -][a-zA-Z]{1})?\b")
    return r1.findall(madde)

madde = kanunMaddesi("5237SA 116/1 119/1 C 58/6 53/1 58 58/7.")
print(madde)
```

Prints:

```
['116/1', '119/1 C']
```

Comment: It really worked, i'll accept your answer. Can you suggest me online regex editor or regex documentation for python.

Comment: @HarunMISTIK The [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/l3v1xE/3) online editor is really nice. On the right side you have an explanation of the regex and you can switch between various regex dialects quickly.